# Detect pen pointerType and pen buttons (compatibility browser and OS)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, svelte

I want to build a simple website that detects a pen (stylus) so that the user can handwrite on a canvas (see the code snippet below). I also want to detect the buttons that are pressed on the stylus while writing. However, I am experiencing compatibility issues, I've noticed the following:

**Windows**

- Chrome/Edge: pointerType = pen gets detected and event.button includes the correct button (either 2 or 5). But: it draws (i.e. pointerup not triggered) even when the pen is just hovering over the screen (not touching).
- Firefox: Works as expected (pen vs mouse detection works and event button are correct, 2 or 5)!

**Linux**

- Chromium: pointer events work as expected but event buttons are not detected correctly (0 or 1).
- Firefox: nothing seems to work: pointerType is mouse and not pen. And event buttons are 0 or 1 instead of 2 or 5

Is there anything I can do to create my web app that correctly detects the pen in general and the "eraser button" (button code 5) and the "select button" (button code 2) in all/most of the browsers?

**Code snippet (I use svelte):**

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    export let thickness, color, tool;

    let canvas;
    let ctx;
    let isDrawing = false;

    onMount(() => {
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    });

    function startDrawing(e) {
        console.log(e.pointerType, e.button)
        if (e.pointerType === "pen") {
            isDrawing = true;

            const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
            const y = e.clientY - rect.top;

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        }
    }

    function draw(e) {
        if (e.pointerType === "pen") {
            if (!isDrawing) return;

            const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
            const y = e.clientY - rect.top;

            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            ctx.lineWidth = thickness;
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    function stopDrawing(e) {
        if (e.pointerType === "pen") {
            if (isDrawing) {
                ctx.closePath();
                isDrawing = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<canvas
    bind:this={canvas}
    on:pointerdown={startDrawing}
    on:pointermove={draw}
    on:pointerup={stopDrawing}
></canvas>
```

Comment: [PointerEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent) has a property of pressure, so I am guessing you could use this to get around your hovering problem (ie. make sure pressure is greater than 0).

Comment: According to MDN `PointerEvent:pointerType` is supported by firefox [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent/pointerType#browser_compatibility). I would say that the issue you have is likely a driver issue (pointing device) Consider checking the driver  version, make sure it's up to date or try an alternative brand. As a web app there is not much you can do apart from looking for details that can only be input from a pen like 2pha comment suggests.

Comment: @Blindman67 Thank you, I will try it with a different pen, maybe the buttons will have the correct number then. However, Firefox on Linux does not even recognize PointerType touch when I touch the screen with my finger, so I don't think that Firefox will recognize the other pen as "pen" instead of "mouse".

Comment: I was not talking about hardware, but a different driver (software) if possible, even a generic driver from another brand might fix the issue.